# Is there a way to apply cell format in xlswriter without setting a value?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Is there a way to apply cell format in `xlswriter` without setting a value? And in terms of `worksheet.write` use of A1 notation, can it be done to a range?

Like:

```
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_border(1)
format.set_bold()
worksheet.write(row=0, col=0, format=format)
worksheet.write('A1:C3', format=format)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `worksheet.write()` you can not specify a range.  You can put it inside a loop and make use of `xlsxwriter.utility.xl_rowcol_to_cell()` which would achieve what you're looking for. [Here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html) is further explanation and examples involving `xlsxwriter.utility.xl_rowcol_to_cell()` from xlsxwriter docs.

Also you can format blank cells by entering `""` as the second argument in `worksheet.write()`.  I've provided a full working example below along with an image of the expected output.

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_border(1)
format.set_bold()
format.set_bg_color("blue")
format.set_num_format('#,##0')

for i in range (0, 3):
    #we're looping through columns
    for j in range (0, 3):
    #we're looping through rows
        cell_reference = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, j, row_abs=True, col_abs=True)
        worksheet.write('%s' % (cell_reference), "" ,format)

workbook.close()
```

[image: Expected excel ouptut]